# Output cache or httpcontext.current.cache for my MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

We are building an MVC application, where there is huge static data to be loaded when the user first time logs in.

Luckily most of the data that has to be loaded during login is all master data and doesn't change for anyusers
But since the size of the master data is huge, we felt it is best to implement caching server side as the browser might not be able to hold the data

I have read an `codeproject` post on `OutputCache` by an Microsoft MVP, he clearly explained what cache does and what are the things to keep in mind while using caching.
So i implemented all that he suggested in my controller by just adding the line

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none", 
    Location=OutputCacheLocation, NoStore=true)]
```

above my ActionMethod.

But i could not debug whether the data is loading from cache or there is another server hit happening.
So my first question is how do i debug whether Output cache is working or not?

And then, in our previous MVC applications we used `httpcontext.current.cache` which worked absolutely fine.
So, here is my second question, which is why should i prefer `OuputCache` over `httpcontext.current.cache` and why not vice versa?

What difference do they offer to caching an application?

**EDIT:1**

This is the method in my login view controller,

```
public ActionResult GetRegions(string Ids)
{
 objRegionsResult = GetRegionsList();
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ids))
 objRegionsResult = objRegionsResult.Where(x => Ids.Split(',').Contains(x.Type.ToString())).ToList();
 return Json(objRegionsResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}



 private List<MORegionMaster> GetRegionsList()
    {
      RequestUri = "Home/GetRegions";
      HttpResponseMessage response = ConnectAPI(RequestUri);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        objRegionsResult = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<MORegionMaster>>().Result;
      }
   }
    return objRegionsResult;
}
```

So the above method is where i hit the api controller, which inturn hits the businesslogic class and subsequently the database and returns the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use OutputCache when we want to cache the result of an action (not static files but cache the business logic result). We use this when we want to serve the data for all users for a particular duration.

We use httpcontext.current.cache when we want to cache some data that can be used multiple times within the same request like caching "Current logged in user object" to avoid multiple db hits.

Also, lifetime of Output Cache is not limited to current http request only but the lifetime of httpcontext.current.cache is up to current http request only.

Comment: No , may be you misunderstood my requirement. My requirement is not to cache js,css files, i need to cache the master data which is being fetched through an API call everytime a user logs in. But that master data remains same for all the different users, so i need to cache data in the server

Comment: do you want to cache business logic only?

Comment: are you fetching master data from api call or using it somewhere inside request?

Comment: For better clarity i have added code in my question, please go through the EDIT:1 Section

Comment: here you can use OutputCache with VaryByParam true for GetRegions action and cache GetRegionsList() result using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache. I am referring MemoryCache because its lifetime is not limited to current http request but httpcontext.current.cache lifetime is up to current request only.

Comment: can you show me how by modifying my code? Because I understood how i can be using Outputcache but am not sure on how to use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache which you have mentioned

Comment: you can use this helper class to save/fetch/remove item from MemoryCache: http://www.textsnip.com/riosox. Also, please make sure to pass the datetime of expiration of item from cache.

Comment: I have used the helper class that you povided and it is working to some extent. but now i have a new problem, i.e. The cache is misbehaving i.e. i dont get appropriate data for the approproiate cache object. Please refer  this SO question i posted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235937/conflict-with-multiple-caches-using-system-runtime-caching